# Importing layer style to new layer

Tags: python, qgis-3, layers, style, pyqgis-3

Running the code through Console Phyton in QGIS Desktop:

```py
copy_renderer_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("map_layer_linestring")[0]
paste_renderer_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=EPSG:4326", "out_layer", "memory")
pr = paste_renderer_layer.dataProvider()
pr.addAttributes(copy_renderer_layer.fields())
paste_renderer_layer.updateFields()

paste_renderer_layer.setRenderer(copy_renderer_layer.renderer())
```

The code works correctly, but after executing it three times, the QGIS Desktop program simply closes! What is the problem?

Comment: What if you try `paste_renderer_layer.setRenderer(copy_renderer_layer.renderer())`, is it what you want?

Comment: Yes! Copy and paste layer settings into a new layer memory